# How do we set the entire form data as a hidden input field value in reactJS (using react-json-schema-forms, react-admin)

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-jsonschema-forms

We are using JSON Schema to Form library to embed a form inside a reactJS page.
We want to set the form (generated from JSON schema) data into a input hidden value to be used later on to pass to a service to save the form value in the database.

e.g. 
See the formData highlighted in the image below attached. this needs to be set as a value to passed to save in the database column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZerP7.png)

Comment: You can try to set `onChange` function to the form. This call wolud be receive same arguments as `onSubmit`. So in the arg you would have `formData`, you can set this to this value to  hidden input.

Comment: We did try this, but the form (react-json-schem-form) gets reset to initial state upon any change in the form. We have a form inside which we have this react-json-schema-form,

Comment: Setting initialValues prop on SimpleForm/TabbedForm with hidden input values solves this? Or does the same problem with onChange happens?

Comment: @gstvg "Setting initialValues prop on SimpleForm/TabbedForm with hidden input values solves this?" - sorry, can you elaborate please? not fully clear on this option you mentioned.

Comment: I assumed based on [react-admin] tag that the form resides inside a SimpleForm/TabbedForm. If so, <SimpleForm initialValues={{firstName: "Chuck", etc...}}/> may help. If not, apologize for my misunderstood